# FileOutputStream - Binary I/O and making int data 10 Java

Tags: for-loop, input, binary

I have a simple OutputStream of 10 integers. I would like to make it a Output with 2 lines. In the book, I can get a 1 line of 10 integers in Java. I would like to make that 1 line to a 2 lines of 5 integers.

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

I have

1 2 3 4 5

7 8 9 10

What should I do?

```
 package chapter_17_test;

import java.io.*;

 public class TestFileStream_2 
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    try (
           // Create an output stream to the file
              FileOutputStream output = new            FileOutputStream("temp_RB29.txt");  //.dat
    ) 
    {
        // Output values to the file
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        output.write(i);
    }

try (
        // Create an input stream for the file
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("temp_RB29.txt");
    ) 
    {
        // Read values from the file
        int test = 1;
        int value;
        while ((value = input.read()) != -1 && test < 11)
        {   
            if ((test % 6) != 0)
            System.out.print(test + " ");
            else
                System.out.println("\n");
            test++;
        }
    }
        System.out.println("");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> ```
>             if ((test % 6) != 0)
>             System.out.print(test + " ");
>             else
>                 System.out.println("\n");
> ```

, note that in one case you print `test + " "`, whereas in the other you print only `"\n"`, without `test`.  That's why 6 is being omitted from your output.  Note also that your output is spread over *three* lines (one blank), not two.

Since you always want to print `test`, it would be cleaner to print it unconditionally. Only the delimiter needs to be printed conditionally.  For example,

```
            System.out.print(test);
            if ((test % 5) != 0)
                System.out.print(' ');
            else
                System.out.println();
```

Comment: I am still not clear about how it works? I put that code in and it does not get 2 lines of 5. Thanks put can you be more detailed?

Comment: Ok I got it! Thanks